# Split a time duration into time segments

Tags: excel-2007

I have an incident start time and end time e.g Sr=tart time of 15/01/2018 11:30 and end time of 16/01/2018 02:40 in an excel table.

How can I split this time range into different time segments.  The segments are:-

```
06:00 - 11:59, 12:00 - 14:59, 15:00 - 17:59, 18:00 - 22:59, 23:00 - 05:59

For 06:00 - 11:59 I would expect 0.50 as this is 30 mins.
For 12:00 - 14:59 I would expect 3.0 for 3 hours. 
For 15:00 - 17:59 I would expect 3.0 for 3 hours again.
For 18:00 - 22:59 this should be 5hrs 
and for 23:00 - 02:40 should be 3.67 hrs.
```

What formula would I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give with the layout as shown below this formula should work:

```
=MIN($D3-F$1,MIN(F$2-F$1,IF($C3<F$2,F$2-$C3+SUM($E3:E3),)))
```

[image: SO48285831 example]

The formula in C3 is:

```
=24*(MOD(A3,1))
```

and in D3:

```
=24*(MOD(B3,1)+INT(B3>INT(A3)))
```